# Max of Product of Random Variables vs replacing one rv with its mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Apologies for the uninformative title.

A paper I am reading states the following fact. If $X$ and $Y$ are **independent** random variables, assume all well-behaved, with means $\bar{X}, \bar{Y}$ then

$$ E \left[ \max \lbrace \bar{X} \bar{Y} - XY,0 \rbrace               \right] \ge E \left[ \max \lbrace \bar{X} \bar{Y} - \bar{X}Y,0 \rbrace               \right].$$

As a reference they give [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FB1SE42) and call this 'a well known finding in martingale theory'. But that's an entire book and I can't seem to find this result.

Any assistance finding or giving the proof, or explaining the intuition, would be helpful!

Comment: Intuition (I am guessing here): there is at least one realization $X \leq \bar{X}$ so $-XY \geq \bar{X}Y$ for every realization of $Y$. The rest follows from there. But I am not sure if this is "right."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(z)=\max(z,0)$ is convex. Let $Z:=\bar{X} \bar{Y} - XY$.
Then by the conditional version of Jensen's inequality (see [1] or [2] or [3]),
$$E \left[ \max \lbrace \bar{X} \bar{Y} - XY,0 \rbrace |Y               \right] =E[f(Z)|Y] \ge f\bigl(E[Z|Y]\bigr)=\max\{\bar{X} \bar{Y} - \bar{X}Y,0\} \,.$$
Taking expectations of both sides (using the tower property of conditional expectation) proves the requested inequality.

[1]  Theorem 3 in https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4410/h19/undervisningsmateriale/jensen.pdf

[2] David Williams, probability with Martingales, Cambridge University Press.

[3] [https://web.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching673/conditioning.pdf](https://web.stat.tamu.edu/%7Esuhasini/teaching673/conditioning.pdf)  Page 153